# Passing data in a pop/back event to a previous view model

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a structure like so :

SessionsView -> CreateSessionView

with view models like so :

SessionsViewModel - List of `Session` objects

CreateSessionViewModel - Single `Session` Object

The user fills in a form in create session, populates the `Session` object on the view model, hits done and I call : `NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true)` to take them back to the list of sessions.

Is there a way of passing my newly created session object back to the previous views Viewmodel and adding it to its list of session objects? I know how to pass params in a `ShowViewModel<TYPE>(PARAM)` command, but not sure how to do it whilst navigating back.

**Update 1 :**

I found 'a' way to do it.. doesn't feel too nice though :

```
var sessionsView = (SessionsView)NavigationController.ViewControllers.FirstOrDefault(vc => vc is SessionsView);
                    var sessionsViewModel = (SessionsViewModel)sessionsView.ViewModel;
                    sessionsViewModel.Sessions.Add(vModel.Session);
                    NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of the return parameter of PopViewControllerAnimated(bool animated).

```
NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
ViewControllerClass viewController = (ViewControllerClass)NavigationController.TopViewController;
viewController.StoreSessionObject(session); <-- you need to create this method
```

Comment: The pop method returns the current view not the one I'm going back to (so in my case its returning CreateSessionView rather than Sessions) so doesn't really give me anything I don't have access to (as I could just do 'this' and get the same ViewController)

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I've actually ended up moving the Sessions list out to a static class so I can more easily share it, but your amended answer definitely answers my question :)